# How do I fix this error. It looks like a type error, but I'm pretty sure that the arrays are of the same type

Tags: python, numpy

How to fix this error?

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'equal' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1'), dtype('<U1')) -> dtype('bool')
```

Here is the code:

```
print(y[0:4], len(y))
print(outs[0:4], len(outs))
corrects = np.equal(outs.astype(str), y.astype(str), casting="safe")
```

`outs` and `y` are both numpy arrays of the same length and type. The printed output is:

```
['1' '1' '1' '1'] 140
['1' '1' '1' '1'] 140
```

It really seems like the two arrays are the same type, so I'm really stumped on this.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.equal` doesn't handle strings.  You can use `np.char.equal`.

Answer (score 0):

But '==' does work:

```
In [22]: x=np.array(['1','1'])
In [23]: x
Out[23]: array(['1', '1'], dtype='<U1')
In [24]: x==x
Out[24]: array([ True,  True])
In [25]: np.equal(x,x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-25-ab75613b91f2>", line 1, in <module>
    np.equal(x,x)
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'equal' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1'), dtype('<U1')) -> dtype('bool')
```

`np.equal` says it is the same as '==', but I'm sure the interpreter translates it to:

```
In [29]: x.__eq__(x)
Out[29]: array([ True,  True])
```

`np.equal` is a `ufunc` with added keywords and methods (like `reduce`), and this notion of `signature`.  Still I'm not sure why it fails with strings.

It is possible that for strings `__eq__` delegates to `np.char.equal` (as mentioned in the other answer), but I'm not sure how to test that.  Maybe there's a difference in timings.  The `char` functions generally operate at list comprehension speeds.

```
In [35]: np.char.equal??
Signature: np.char.equal(x1, x2)
Source:   
@array_function_dispatch(_binary_op_dispatcher)
def equal(x1, x2):
    """
    Return (x1 == x2) element-wise.

    Unlike `numpy.equal`, this comparison is performed by first
    stripping whitespace characters from the end of the string.  This
    behavior is provided for backward-compatibility with numarray.
```

### time test

Make a large string array, and matching integer one:

```
In [36]: X = np.repeat(x, 100000)
In [37]: X.shape
Out[37]: (200000,)
In [39]: A = np.arange(x.shape[0])
In [40]: timeit A==A
636 ns ± 5.23 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [41]: timeit X==X
2.07 ms ± 359 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So the string comparison is definitely slower, though `np.char.equal` is slower still.

```
In [42]: timeit np.char.equal(X,X)
5.09 ms ± 1.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And string times:

```
In [43]: Xl = X.tolist()
In [44]: timeit [i==j for i,j in zip(Xl, Xl)]
13.6 ms ± 27.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```